# Launching SOAP UI via terminal not working, gives "java; not found"

Tags: java, installation, soapui

I have downloaded java8 and then created a folder "java" in "/usr/local". Later I set the JAVA_HOME and PATH using export.
`echo $JAVA_HOME` output `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20`

Now, when I open terminal and type `java -version` it prompts to choose any package from below to install java. But when I do `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` it gives

```
java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-ea-b23)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b22, mixed mode)
```

and when I run 
`sh /home/SOAPUI_HOME/soapui-4.0.1/bin/soapui.sh` gives

```
================================
=
= SOAPUI_HOME = /home/SOAPUI_HOME/soapui-4.0.1
=
================================
/home/SOAPUI_HOME/soapui-4.0.1/bin/soapui.sh: 141: /home/SOAPUI_HOME/soapui-4.0.1/bin/soapui.sh: java: not found
```

Comment: You've entered all of these commands in the same shell, or in different shells?

Comment: I have tried in different terminals and same terminals. But it gave same results...

Comment: So what's line 141 of soapui.sh ?

Comment: @paul `export` sets environment variables on a per-shell basis. You *need* to be in the same shell that you've run `export` in.

Comment: Oh, @PatrickCollins, I am sorry, while setting java home and path , I was in same shell. If java wasn't properly installed I would've not been able to run other apps which need java support like eclipse and running webdrive scripts.

Comment: @paul Okay. We need to see the relevant section of `soapui.sh`, then.

Comment: it is `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI "$@"`

Comment: @paul Try just running `/home/.../soapui.sh` instead of `sh /home/.../soapui.sh`. Run `chmod +x` if necessary.

Comment: Just did, and give same error that I reported above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoapUI doesn't use JAVA_HOME in its launcher .sh files. You could add /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/ before java on line 141 (if you are using SoapUI 4.0.1, but I would suggest to upgrade to 5.0.0, then it's line 72).

Another solution would be to to make sure your java installation is the PATH variable.

Third, and easiest in my opinion, is to download the installer version of SoapUI. It is a .sh file which installs both SoapUI and Java.

Comment: I wanna go 3rd option, but how to run that in terminal. I tried `bash SoapUI-x32-5.0.0.sh` and it says `gzip: sfx_archive.tar: Function not implemented` `I am sorry, but the installer file seems to be corrupted.
If you downloaded that file please try it again. If you
transfer that file with ftp please make sure that you are
using binary mode.`

Comment: The installer should be 119226387 bytes and the md5 hash of it should be 0b4c4244224cd985f2cc1ef4a0a00e36. Maybe the download of the installer failed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the Internet Connection, because in the logs I saw many HttpConnection errors. Launch SOAP UI from terminal

```
sh /Applications/SoapUI-5.1.3.app/Contents/java/app/bin/soapui.sh
```

and then turn on the internet again.

Answer (score 0):

When I want my systems Java version to overrule the SoapUI Java version, I rename the jre folder within the soapUI folder to temp or whatever. After that SoapUI picks up the Java version that you are running on your system.